# Loop that runs through check box and displays only selected answer

Tags: jquery, function

There are set of check boxes and answers (hidden). When a user checks the checkbox and clicks the button it suppose to show the related answer. Each check box is associated with an answer. I was able to the function work for one Check box. but how do I run a loop so that the function goes through the loop and show the answer based on the selected check box. I couldn't figure out how to create a variable to loop through.

The code is set up at: http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/JcvHb/#base

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$(".answer").hide(); //Hiding all the answers         

$("#showMe").click(function(event){       
    var isChecked = $('[name=oneA]').is(':checked');
    if(isChecked)
      $(".oneA").show();
    else
        $(".oneA").hide();
       });
 });​
```

HTML

```
<div class="options">
    <div class="optionOne">
        <h2>Section Heading</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneA">option One A<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneB">option One B<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneC">option One C<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneD">option One D<br>
    </div><!--optionOne-->

    <button type="button" id="showMe">Show Me</button>

</div><!--option-->

<div class="answers">
    <div class="answerOne">
        <h2>Answer Heading</h2>
        <div class="oneA answer" name="oneA">
            <p>Content from one A</p>
        </div><!--oneA-->
        <div class="oneB answer" name="oneB">
            <p>Content from one B</p>
        </div><!--oneB-->
        <div class="oneC answer" name="oneC">
            <p>Content from one C</p>        
        </div><!--oneC-->
        <div class="oneD answer" name="oneD">
            <p>Content from one D</p>
        </div><!--oneD-->
    </div><!--answerOne-->
</div><!--answers-->​
```

Comment: Will you have more than just `optionOne`; will there be an `optionTwo`?

Comment: Haha +1 for asking a question with 7 different functional answers :-p

Comment: When you try to extend this to more than one option you will find only one answer that will work. Hint [hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11159505/144665).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change you click handler like this:

```
$("#showMe").click(function(event){

    // get all checked items
    var checked = $('.optionOne').find(':checked');

    // for each of them
    $.each(checked, function() {

        // re-hide them all
        $(".answer").hide();

        // get the name
        var name = this.name;

        // and show the div that has the same class name
        $('.' + name).show();

    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/R5649/)**

Comment: I think i would do that but on top of that, instead of just showing it, i think that you would do something like:

    <div id = "ans"></div>
    $("#ans").html($("."+name).clone().wrap("<p>").parent().html());

That way, the answer will always show at the correct spot and style the answer div to be where ever the client wants it.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/tQtTf/

```
$(function(){

    $(".answer").hide(); //Hiding all the answers   

    $("#showMe").click(function(event){ 
        $(".answer").hide();        
        $('.options :checked').each(function(){
            $('.answer.'+$(this).attr('name')).show();
        });
    });   

});​
```

As long as you use the same system this is extendable to infinite options / answers.

Comment: This is a great answer to this question :-)

Comment: @JasperMogg Thanks. Nice to be appreciated. I don't understand why OPs don't see that as well.

Comment: I guess extensibility isn't the first thing in the OP's mind. Tbf, if you're asking this kind of Q, you probably haven't planned that far ahead...

Comment: Although, answers like these are why I love this site - it's beautiful to see a way of doing something you hadn't even considered.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $answers = $(".answer").hide();

    $("#showMe").click(function()
    {
        $answers.hide();

        $('input:checked').each(function()
        {
            $answers.filter( '.' + this.name ).show();
        });
    });
});​
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JcvHb/7/

Answer (score 1):

Start off by giving the checkboxes the same name, but with different values.

```
<div class="optionOne">
    <h2>Section Heading</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="oneA">option One A<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="oneB">option One B<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="oneC">option One C<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value="oneD">option One D<br>
</div><!--optionOne-->
```

Then you can loop through all the checked checkboxes and you will have the value of the desired div name.

```
$("#showMe").click(function(event){       
    var isChecked = $('[name=one]').is(':checked');
    $(isChecked).each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("div[name=" + value + "]").show();
    });
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just collect all the `:checked` inputs and iterate over them with `.each()` showing the element with the class that's the same as that checkbox name:

```
$("#showMe").click(function(event){   
    var $checked = $('.optionOne').find('input:checked');
    $checked.each(function(i, el){
        $('.' + $(this).attr('name')).show();
    });            
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JcvHb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a pre-selection of checkboxes?
This works in every case:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcvHb/15/)

**JS**

```
$("#showMe").click( function(){
    $(".answer").hide();
    $(':checkbox:checked').each( function() {
        $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).show();
    });
}).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can only use jQuery 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/JcvHb/11/).

Changed your JS to the following -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".answer").hide(); //Hiding all the answers (could be done in CSS?)

    $("#showMe").click(function(event){  
        $(".answer").hide();
        $('input [name^=one]').each(function(index, element){
            $(element).is(':checked') ? $('div [name=' + $(element).attr("name") + ']').show() : null;
        })
    })

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it up and running in JSFiddle, but here is the source code as well.
http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/SEfNF/18/

**HTML**

```
<div class="options">
    <div id="checkbox-options" class="optionOne">
        <h2>Section Heading</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneA">option One A<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneB">option One B<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneC">option One C<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="oneD">option One D<br>
    </div><!--optionOne-->

    <button type="button" id="showMe">Show Me</button>

</div><!--option-->

<div id="answers" class="answers">
    <div class="answerOne">
        <h2>Answer Heading</h2>
        <div id="oneA" class="oneA answer" name="oneA">
            <p>Content from one A</p>
        </div><!--oneA-->
        <div id="oneB" class="oneB answer" name="oneB">
            <p>Content from one B</p>
        </div><!--oneB-->
        <div id="oneC" class="oneC answer" name="oneC">
            <p>Content from one C</p>        
        </div><!--oneC-->
        <div id="oneD" class="oneD answer" name="oneD">
            <p>Content from one D</p>
        </div><!--oneD-->
    </div><!--answerOne-->
</div><!--answers-->​
```

---

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    // Get all of the single answers
    var $answers = $('.answer', '#answers');
    // The show me button
    var $showMe = $('#showMe');
    // All of the checkboxes
    var $checkboxes = $('input', '#checkbox-options');

    // hide the answers    
    $answers.hide();

    $showMe.click(function() {
        // Get all the checked ones
        var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(":checked");
        // Loop through them and show the ones that have
        // been checked
        $.each($checked, function(index, value) { 
            var $answerToShow = $('#' + value.name);
            $answerToShow.show();
        });
    });
});​
```